# Ready to use c++ library for Embedding Python in C++

Tags: library, python, c++

I have working software which is built in Visual C++. Now, I have to convert some module of this software to Python. I want to send an array to the Python module from a C++ program, run a Python script and return a value to the main C++ program.  I see Python.boost and pybind11 and tried to build and use but, I could not build it properly. Is there any other library, which does not require it to be built, that I can directly use in my environment?

Comment: Are you looking for a header-only library? As, otherwise - you would _have_ to build it. Or do you mean you want pre-built binaries? You can get pre-built Boost binaries for various platforms (including Windows I believe).

Comment: Why do you need a library? the C++ program can run a Python script an capture its output. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227128/how-to-use-a-c-program-to-run-a-command-on-terminal) for instance

Answer (score 1):

There are three alternatives which come to my mind.

## [SWIG](http://swig.org/)

SWIG is an external program which you feed your C++ header file and which generates the Python interface code for you.

## [Boost.Python](http://boost.org/libs/python)

Boost.Python is a high-level object oriented interface to the Python C-API.

## [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/)

Is the successor of Boost.Python.  It uses C++11 to provide more convenient interfaces.